# Can't place my footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble placing the footer at the bottom of my page. I tried to set the html and body tag to 100% height at relative position, but it just wont work.

Here's a screenshot of my page:
[Screenshot of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCXgH.png)

And here is the code of my footer:

```css
    footer {
       background: black;
       padding: 10px 0;
       box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #000000;
       text-align: right;
       width: 100%;
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       min-height: 74px;
    }

    .footerlogo {
       float: left;
    }

    .info {
       color: white;
       font-size: 10px;
       margin: 0;
       margin-left: 50px;
       max-width: 301px;
    }
```

```html
            <!--Footer-->

        <section class="container-fluid paddingzero">
            <header class="row">
                <footer class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <img class="footerlogo" src="Images/logo-20.png" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-6">
                        <p class="info">Tlf: +45 50 38 36 45</p>
                        <p class="info">Adresse: Søndergade 6b  Grenaa</p>
                        <p class="info">E-mail: Nee.Kolind@gmail.com</p>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </header>
        </section>
```

Hope you can help me, and just ask me if you need some more information :)

Comment: Yes i am using bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 
HTML

```
<section class="container-fluid paddingzero fixedBottom">
    ...
</section>
```

CSS

```
.fixedBottom{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

And then footer like below:

```
footer {
   background: black;
   padding: 10px 0;
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #000000;
   text-align: right;
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 74px;
}
```